# How to set context-param in spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, context-param

In the classic web.xml type configuration you could configure context parameters like so

web.xml

```
...
<context-param>
  <param-name>p-name</param-name>
  <param-value>p-value</param-value>
</context-param>
...
```

How is this achieved in spring-boot. I have a filter that requires parameters.

I'm using `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and have included `<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>` in my pom.

Comment: Check out docs for application.properties options. Many of them you can resolve in just one line :) http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can set parameters using the `server.servlet.context-parameters` application property. For example:

```
server.servlet.context-parameters.p-name=p-value
```

In Spring Boot 1.x, which is no longer supported, this property was named `server.context-parameters`:

```
server.context-parameters=p-name=p-value
```

Alternatively, you can configure parameters programmatically by declaring a `ServletContextInitializer` bean:

```java
@Bean
public ServletContextInitializer initializer() {
    return servletContext -> {
        servletContext.setInitParameter("p-name", "p-value");
    };
}
```

Comment: Your answer came up in some rather extensive research that I am doing about how to define a filter list using Spring Boot.  I have been documenting my research.  Are you willing to comment on it?  Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36489253/api-url-has-an-empty-filter-list-in-spring-boot-security

Comment: @Andy how to set context-param programmatically for servlet 2.5?

Comment: Spring Boot does not support Servlet 2.5.

Comment: It has changed to "server.servlet.context-parameters.p-name=-value"

Comment: In newest spring boot `server.context_parameters` is not working anymore - now this parameter is: `server.servlet.context-parameters`

Answer (score 7):

You can actually achieve this using Java config. If you have filter that requires some parameters, just put them in your application.yml (or .properties), inject them using `@Value` in your config class and register them in `FilterRegistrationBean`.

For example:

```
@Value("${myFilterParam}")
private String myFilterParam;

@Bean(name="myFilter")
public FilterRegistrationBean myFilter() {
    FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new MyFilter());
    filterRegistrationBean.setInitParameters(Collections.singletonMap("p-name", "p-value"));
    return filterRegistrationBean;
}
```

Also JavaDoc for `FilterRegistrationBean`:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/FilterRegistrationBean.html

**Update**

You can register parameters for servlet context in `SpringBootServletInitializer#onStartup()` method. Your Application class can extend the `SpringBootServletInitializer` and you can override the `onStartup` method and set the parameters there. Example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        servletContext.setInitParameter("p-name", "p-value");
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

}
```

Other alternative is to define `ServletContextInitializer` bean as suggested by Andy Wilkinson.

Comment: Apologies, I was meant to ask about context params, not init params. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 5):

Since Spring Boot 2.0.0 they updated the way to add context param:

```
server.servlet.context-parameters.yourProperty.
```

You can see more updates on this [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0.0-M1-Release-Notes)

Answer (score 2):

Also you can define InitParameterConfiguringServletContextInitializer in your configuration. Example:

```
@Bean
public InitParameterConfiguringServletContextInitializer initParamsInitializer() {
    Map<String, String> contextParams = new HashMap<>();
    contextParams.put("p-name", "-value");
    return new InitParameterConfiguringServletContextInitializer(contextParams);
}
```