# How to make awesome font work in Spring Boot with PrimeFaces

Tags: spring-boot, primefaces

I have [sample Spring Boot project for PrimeFaces](https://github.com/code-not-found/jsf-primefaces/tree/master/jsf-primefaces-spring-boot) and looking for a way to make awesomefont to work as shown in [PF Showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/fa.xhtml).

So I created awesomefont-test.xhtml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
  <title>Awesomefont Test</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>

    <p:commandButton value="Edit" icon="fa fa-fw fa-edit" type="button"/>

</h:body>
</html>
```

and the result is (no icon)

[image: button without awesomefont icon]

I tried several things:

**1.) web.xml**

I created `web.xml` and I tried to put it next to faces-config.xml (which is in `jsf-primefaces-spring-boot/src/main/resources/META-INF/`).

I tried to put it to `jsf-primefaces-spring-boot/src/main/resources/WEB-INF/` not working too.

I do not know how to check it is read.

content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

</web-app>
```

**2.) SpringBootServletInitializer**

```java
package com.codenotfound.primefaces;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringPrimeFacesApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringPrimeFacesApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        servletContext.setInitParameter("primefaces.FONT_AWESOME", "true");
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
    }

}
```

source: [How to set context-param in spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26639475/how-to-set-context-param-in-spring-boot/26648258)

**3.) application.properties**

From same source I tried to set property in application.properties

```
server.context_parameters.primefaces.FONT_AWESOME=true
```

also I tried variant with

```
server.servlet.context-parameters.primefaces.FONT_AWESOME=true
```

**4.) webjars**

This is a workaround, I just wanted to give it a try.

I also tried to add webjars dependencies (and modify xhtml) as described here - http://www.littlebigextra.com/add-bootstrap-css-jquery-to-springboot-mvc/

but none of those approaches worked for me.

Comment: Better article for webjarshttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891768/how-to-use-font-awesome-from-webjars-org-with-jsf/28652968#28652968. The article you refer to is not correct for JSF... And using WebJars is in mo opinion the better way. PF should not have included it themselves

Comment: And FA from PrimeFaces is not supported in PF 1.0

Comment: @Kukeltje I tried your advice, but it is not working for me - I added dependency in maven + `<h:outputStylesheet library="webjars" name="font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome-jsf.css" />` which is rendered in page source as `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="RES_NOT_FOUND">` I'm using PF 6.1

Comment: Finally, I noticed, there is version in link and I had different as dependency. Also I tried `fas` class, but with 4.x I had to use `fa`.

Comment: So it works now?

Comment: Yes, it works with version 4.7.0, with 5.0.9 I had `href="RES_NOT_FOUND"` again on page.

Comment: I made it work using the font awesome javascript library instead.  
Ex.
    <script src="fontawesome.js"></script>
    <script src="fa-solid.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

After defining the dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
  <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
  <version>4.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

You need to add config into `application.yml`:

```
jsf:
  primefaces: 
    FONT_AWESOME: true
```

or if use `application.properties` add:

```
jsf.primefaces.FONT_AWESOME=true
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a web xml, just add the dependency and in your `application.properties` add this:

```
jsf.primefaces.font-awesome=true
```

And if you what to configure a theme add this:

```
jsf.primefaces.theme= theme-name
```